# How to identity if a device is a POS machine in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, device, point-of-sale, info

I am using the package [device_info_plus: ^3.2.0](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus/versions/3.2.0) to get the device information.

I am currently using a POS machine that is a Q1 model. Is there a way to identify if the device is a POS machine?

Because the example section for this package also provides the build.type, but it just returns "user". I get the same response for my Samsung galaxy note 8 while that is a mobile phone.

I will like to know if there is a way to identify if a device is a mobile or a POS machine. This will be a great way for me to identify if its a POS machine so that I can enable kiosk mode **only** for **POS** machines.

I tried to see what the build.type returns from the package but its not what I am expecting.

Comment: hello, were you be able get solution to this?